# Map dataframe values to index of a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I've factorized my previous dataframe using this code

```
df['name'], mapping = df['name'].factorize()
```

Now I am trying to get the same factorized value for my new dataframe using the variable mapping

Mapping

```
Index(['Ranny','Bob','Timmy','Lisa'],
  dtype='object')
```

My new dataframe

```
╔════════════════╗
║ Name    Apples ║
╠════════════════╣
║ Lisa      5    ║
║ Timmy     3    ║  
║ Lisa      2    ║
║ Bob       1    ║
╚════════════════╝
```

The dataframe I want after mapping the column name to the list

```
╔════════════════╗
║ Name    Apples ║
╠════════════════╣
║ 3         5    ║
║ 2         3    ║  
║ 3         2    ║
║ 1         1    ║
╚════════════════╝
```

I'm not sure how to do it. I tried to a loop but it takes too much time when the dataset is big. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly , you can use [`pd.Index.get_Indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) here:

```
df2['Name'] = mapping.get_indexer(df2['Name'])
print(df)
```

---

```
   Name  Apples
0     3       5
1     2       3
2     3       2
3     1       1
```